# WSO2 Stream Processor (SP) Error "could not initialize carbon deployment engine"

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator, event-stream-processing

I have an issue with my web IDE. The WSO2 SP or siddhi-tooling-5.1.2 starts up as you would expect and I can open the website. However, in the console upon startup it gives this error.

[image: Picture of ERROR]

This is an issue as I am unable to interact with the web IDE once opened with things such as saving files etc. When I do try and save files it just says there is an internal server error. Which is the above :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I have made sure to set my JAVA_HOME as Java 1.8_144 as a environment variable and my computer has all other prerequisites needed to run it.

I have also tried setting the CARBON_HOME environment variable as the SP_HOME directory.

Online there have been some suggested solutions to manually fix this issue by creating a deployment folder in these areas of use but this was for another WSO2 product and I am a little confused about what it all that meant.

I am very new to this so I do not mean to be ignorant and any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated, thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

### NOT ABLE TO EDIT WEB IDE ERROR SOLUTION

Hi so the error shown was solved by the lovely helper "ycr" but the web IDE still wasn't able to be edited so to fix that I have to make sure that all the empty files where in the SP_HOME/wso2/editor/deployment folder (i.e. an empty workspace folder) as when I extracted, it didnt extract them with it for some reason. Hope this also helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

The Paths are tricky in windows when it comes to WOS2 products. The reason could be the long path you have or spaces in the folder names. Hence can you move the distribution up the directory hierarchy to a directory which doesn't have any spaces in the name and try from there. For example

```
C:\workspace\sp
```

Comment: Thank you for the great help! That solved the error!